# Python datetime.today() to handle timezone

Tags: python, datetime

Hi apologies on basic python datetime question but I am a little confused:

I want to just have a variable the prints today's date, with consideration to the time zone the program I am running it in. Let's say California.

```
import datetime
import pytz
utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
pst_now = utc_now.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))
x = pst_now.isoformat()
```

for x it returns :

```
2020-01-13T17:43:56.155556-08:00
```

how can I get it to return:

```
2020-01-13
```

I tried:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d)
```

But it did not work

Comment: _But it did not work_ Saying just "it didn't work" isn't enough to help us solve the problem.  Tell us what it _actually_ did, and what you wanted instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to return the time of the local machine, no need to deal with timezones directly in your code, you can use the now function of datetime.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I got: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Looks like you have one too many datetimes in there somewhere. If you're using import datetime then my code should work. If you're using from datetime import datetime then remove one of the datetimes from each of my references.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, now I get : AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: well actually sorry, yes I got the date to return but the whole issue is still there - it is showing '2020-01-14' - which is tomorrow, my machine reflects 2020-01-13

Comment: @004 what is the date you are expecting on your machine and where it is showing `2020-01-14` ?

Comment: Machine is showing 2020-01-13 and returned date is showing 2020-01-14

Comment: @0004 time might not have been configured correctly on the machine

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a string. `pst_now` is a datetime object which, when the method `.isoformat()` is called on it, produces a string.

Solution: call `strftime` on `pst_now`:

```
x = pst_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `pst_now` to a `date()` object:

```
pst_now.date().isoformat()
```

> '2020-01-13'